# I need help calculating the total of a receipt from an array

Tags: c#

My code is using an array to store data from a users inputs, and a problem I have run into is taking the subtotal from the array to display that after the array is displayed. I am having an issue displaying the array in the way I need it to be, but I will worry about that later. I am new to C# so any help is appreciated.

```
int[,] quantity = new int[100, 4];
decimal[,] price = new decimal[100, 4];
decimal subtotal = 0;
string[,] items = new string[100, 4];
int i, j, count;

count = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{

    Console.Write("Enter Item Name(enter 0 to stop): ");
    items[i, 0] = Console.ReadLine();
    if (items[i, 0] == "0")
               break;
    else
        count++;

    Console.Write("Enter Item Price: ");
    items[i, 1] = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Enter Item Quantity: ");
    items[i, 2] = Console.ReadLine();
    items[i, 3] = (Convert.ToDouble(items[i, 1]) * Convert.ToDouble(items[i, 2])).ToString();
}

Console.WriteLine("         Your Receipt");
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(items[i, j], " ");
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
Console.WriteLine("\n{0} Items total: ", count);
Console.WriteLine("Subtotal:                     ${0}", subtotal);
decimal tax = subtotal * 0.065M;
Console.WriteLine("Tax (0.065%)                  ${0}", tax);
decimal total = tax + subtotal;
Console.WriteLine("Total:                        ${0}", total);
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you need to use arrays like this?  C# offers a much clearer way of recording this information.

Comment: you don't assign subtotal anywhere. What is it *supposed* to be?

Comment: this is Basic code in C#.. fun

Answer (score -1):

To calculate the subtotal, you can make the following modifications

Replace:

```
items[i, 3] = (Convert.ToDouble(items[i, 1]) * Convert.ToDouble(items[i, 2])).ToString();
```

With:

```
decimal lineTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(items[i, 1]) * Convert.ToDecimal(items[i, 2]);
items[i, 3] = lineTotal.ToString();
subtotal += lineTotal; // Add this line to calculate subtotal
```

Also, you can replace the inner loop for a single line display

```
for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(items[i, j], " ");
}
```

with this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Item: {items[i,0]}, Price: ${items[i,1]}, Quantity: {items[i,2]}, Total: ${items[i,3]}");
```